# Misunderstanding of lowering indexes using Euclidian metric

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

One may define a vector field in $R$ and see how its components transform under a basis transformation.

$ v= v^{u}\partial _{u} $

In principle, the components transform as contravariant such that the vector is invariant. Likewise, 1-forms are maps from vector fields to functions. I have seen they are also call duals. Its components transform as covariant. Until here, I like to see this names as labels to remember how they transform. My misunderstanding comes from the fact that if we consider the euclidian metric as a 1-form

$g(v,.) = v_{u}f^{u}$

where $v_{u} = g_{uv}v^{v}$

we can take the components of a vector field and obtain covariant components of the 1-form. But as the metric is simply identity, we obtain the same components. However, they still transform the opposite. How is that possible?

I have read the reason in classical mechanics these labels does not appear since both of the are the same, but I still see they transform differently, therefore they should be mentioned somehow. I would like to see your clarifications.

Adding: Perhaps my question is better stated like this:

A magnetic field $B$ may be considered a 2-form so that $dB=0$. That same goes for the Electric Field in case is electrostatic which turns out to be a 1-form. I somehow always considered them as vector fields. Now their components transform differentely depending on how you picture them. But to me, that is somehow inconsistent since we are talking about the same field. I hope that makes my doubt clear.

Comment: But when you've done the transformation $g$ transforms too such that its components are no longer the identity.

Comment: If you stick to rotations or more genral orthogonal tranformations (refections)  the the metric does not change, but then covariant and contravariant  vectors transform in the same manner under orthogonal changes of basis.

Comment: please see my edit, thanks

Comment: @jacob1729: That should be an answer.

Comment: @jacob1729 The identity transforms into itself.

Comment: @BenCrowell The identity transforms into itself.

Comment: @my2cts no it doesn't, see the aside in my answer. The identity matrix $\delta^i_j$ does, but a two index tensor $g_{ij}$ numerically equal to the identity matrix does not.

Comment: @jacob1729 I am not convinced. Are you sure that under a Cartesian rotation $g_{ij}$ does not transform into itself in for example spherical coordinates? Note that a Cartesian rotation  is a _translation_ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @my2cts under rotations, yes you're right. OP never mentions rotations and I think its natural to assume they are referring to general coordinate transformations. These leave $\delta^i_j$ intact but change $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @jacob1729 He is talking about coordinate systems where "the metric is simply identity". This excludes for example spherical coordinates. Your answer is an answer to a more complex question than is asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the components of a vector and the components of its covector dual happen to be equal for a particular choice of basis does not imply that they will be equal in any other basis.  This equality relies on the fact that the basis is orthonormal, a property which is preserved only if the change of basis is orthogonal; if it isn't, then the equality between contravariant and covariant components will be lost.

If we write the transformation rules for contravariant and covariant components in matrix form, then the contravariant components transform via multiplication by the inverse Jacobian matrix $J^{-1}$ while the covariant components transform via multiplication by $J^T$, and it is in this sense that we say they transform in opposite ways to one another.  If the transformation is such that $J$ is orthogonal, then the covariant and contravariant components have the same transformation rules.  I'll now work this out in more detail.

---

**Vector Transformation Rules**

Under a change of coordinates $x\rightarrow y$, the basis vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ transform as follows:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^i}}_{= J^j_{\ \ i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$$

Because a vector is a basis independent geometrical object, the *components* of the vector must transform the "opposite" way

$$V^i_{(x)} \rightarrow V^i_{(y)} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}}_{= (J^{-1})^i_{\ \ j}} V^j_{(x)}$$
so the vector itself remains unchanged
$$\mathbf V = V^i_{(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \rightarrow V^i_{(y)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} = V^j_{(x)} \underbrace{\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial y^i}}_{= \delta^k_j} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^k}=V^j_{(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \mathbf V$$

For this reason, we call the components of $\mathbf V$ *contravariant* (where the prefix "contra-" means "opposite").

---

**Covector Transformation Rules**

The dual basis $\{dx^i\}$ is defined such that $$dx^i\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = \delta^i_j.$$

Applying the same change of coordinates and demanding that this relationship remain true for the transformed covector basis $\{dy^i\}$, we must have that

$$dx^i \rightarrow dy^i = \underbrace{\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}}_{= (J^{-1})^i_{\ \ j}} dx^j$$
so
$$dy^i \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial y^j}\right) = \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^k}dx^k \left(\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial y^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\right) = \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^k}\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial y^j} \underbrace{dx^k\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\right)}_{=\delta^k_l}$$
$$= \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial y^j} = \delta^i_j$$

The corresponding components of a covector must transform in the opposite sense to the covector basis (because covectors are basis-independent objects too), so the covector components must transform as follows:

$$\omega_{(x)i}\rightarrow \omega_{(y)i} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^i}}_{= J^j_{\ \ i}} \omega_{(x)j}$$

Comparing this to the beginning of this answer, you can see that covector components transform in the *same* way as the basis vectors, so we call these components *covariant*.

---

We have therefore shown that if we define $\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j} \equiv J^i_{\ \ j}$, then covariant components transform as
$$V^i \rightarrow (J^{-1})^i_{\ \ j} V^j$$
and covariant covector components transform as
$$\omega_i \rightarrow J^j_{\ \ i} \omega_j = (J^T)_i^{\ \ j} \omega_j$$

If it so happens that the Jacobian matrix is *orthogonal*, then $J^{-1}=J^T$ and  contravariant components and covariant components have the same transformation rules.  This is usually the case in the contexts you describe, where our basis changes tend to be simple rotations.  If our change of basis were not orthogonal (e.g. switching from a Cartesian coordinate basis to a polar coordinate basis), then contravariant components would be transformed with $J^{-1}$, while covariant components would be transformed with $J^T$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mostly confused by the fact that the components of a vector $v^i$ transform differently to the components of its dual $v_i$, yet in all coordinate systems they are related via $v_i=g_{ij}v^j$ where $g_{ij}$ is the metric, and for Euclidean space with a Cartesian coordinate system takes the form of the identity matrix. So if they always have the same components, how can those components transform differently?

But the metric can be Euclidean and not be the identity! For instance in polar coordinates we have $g_{ij}=\text{diag}(1,r^2)$. So the answer is simply that $g_{ij}$ also transforms such that:

$$v^i \mapsto \tilde{v}^{i} = (J^{-1})^i_a v^a $$
$$g_{ij} \mapsto \tilde{g}_{ij} = J^a_i J^b_j g_{ab}$$

$$v_i \mapsto \tilde{v}_i = \tilde{g}_{ij}\tilde{v}^j = J^j_i v_j$$

(where I've skipped over the actual algebra of getting the $J$'s to cancel).

---

Aside: 
This might be surprising because the identity matrix is the same in all bases, so what's going on? The answer is that the correct statement is that the identity transform is represented by the identity matrix in all bases, but $g_{ij}$ is a two lower index object so does not represent a linear transform but a bilinear form. These do not transform via:

$$L \mapsto L' = JLJ^{-1}$$

as linear transforms do but instead by:

$$B \mapsto B' = J B J^{T} $$

(I apologise if I've broken some convention about which matrix is transposed and which is inverted.)

Thus the coordinate changes that leave the metric as the identity are those whose Jacobians are orthogonal matrices i.e. rotations.